# Protractor : How to Call Rest API POST with header and body

Tags: protractor

I have setup steps before running my e2e test in which I have to create users before I execute my test. I am using Protractor's `Request` API to make REST API POST calls but I'm not sure how can I pass data (body) and headers in the request. My request should look like this:

`URL : 'rest/users', Headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}, body: {"userName": "user1", "domain": "1", "password": "password1", "userID": "1"}`

I am trying to do something like this:

```
var request = require('request');

function createuser(url){
    console.log("complete url = ", browser.baseUrl+url);
    request({
        method: 'POST',
        uri: browser.baseUrl+url,
        multipart: [
            {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            {body: {
                'userName': 'test3',
                'tenantKey': '0',
                'password': 'Test3',
                 'userID': '3'}
            }
        ],
        function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                return console.error('User Creation failed:', error);
            }
            console.log('User Creation successful!  Server responded with:', body);
         }
     })
};
createuser('rest/1.0/dev/users');
```

It's throwing the following error (I'm not sure what am I doing wrong):

```
Error: Body attribute missing in multipart.
Stack:
Error: Body attribute missing in multipart.
    at C:\code\ui\dgui\node_modules\request\lib\multipart.js:35:36
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Multipart.isChunked (C:\code\ui\dgui\node_modules\request\lib\multipart.js:33:11)
    at Multipart.onRequest (C:\code\ui\dgui\node_modules\request\lib\multipart.js:104:22)
    at Request.multipart (C:\code\ui\dgui\node_modules\request\request.js:1176:19)
    at Request.init (C:\code\ui\dgui\node_modules\request\request.js:424:10)
    at new Request (C:\code\ui\dgui\node_modules\request\request.js:142:8)
    at request (C:\code\ui\dgui\node_modules\request\index.js:55:10)
    at createuser (C:\code\ui\dgui\tests\e2e\TestSuites\_BVT\_CreateNewUsers2.js:36:2)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\code\ui\dgui\tests\e2e\TestSuites\_BVT\_CreateNewUsers2.js:49:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to achieve this using 'superagent', this is how I am using:

```
CallRestAPI:

var request = require( "superagent" );
var PostUrl = browser.baseUrl + 'rest/1.0/dev/users';

exports.CreateUsers = function(body){
console.log("Executing CreateUsers");
var data = '{' +body + '}';
console.log("Send data in post request = ", data);

 request.post( PostUrl ).set('Content-Type', 'application/json').send(data).end(function(err,res){
     if(err){
            console.log("CreateUsers post error= ", err )
        } else{
            console.log("CreateUsers post response = ", res.status)
        }
 });            
};
```

Using this Function as:

```
var Common = require('../.././helpers/CallRestAPI');
Common.CreateUsers('"userName": "test1", "tenantKey": "0", "password": "Test1", "userID": "1"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have managed it in my code with request validation when eg. access token is wrong or app do not respond. Imo it's better approach because your proposition always passes test what can give false positive.

```
    exports.authorize = function (login, pass) {
    var action = function () {
        return getToken().then(function (token) {
            var dfd = protractor.promise.defer();
            req.post(getBackendUrl() + '/authorize/authenticate')
                .set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('RequestId', uuid.v4()).set('Authorization', token)
                .send({"login": login, "pass": pass})
                .end(function (err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        dfd.reject(res)
                    } else {
                        dfd.fulfill(res.body);
                    }
                });
            return dfd.promise;
        })
    };
    return browser.controlFlow().execute(action);
};
```

Endpoint authorize returns 200 status code for both - valid and not valid credentials so in specific test it can be distincted by simple jasmine expect like:

```
        var Initialize = require('..initialize');
        var successResponse = {status: 'success'};
        expect(Initialize.authorize('some_login', 'some_password')).toEqual(successResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://sbx-office-api.b2bcloud.com/rmi/v1/books/list?type=fetchall',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlFrTTFRemt6UlVJNE5UazNSVVJGTUVVNU5rTXlNVVpFT0RJek5EQTNPRFkyTVVaRVFrVXdSZyJ9.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.D5MoBVJ2lWZ7b3FCZtMQkmdMxJot8SCR1-Oso-wponPtF2y6kLxKK5dUftI_yzydvaJsZ9mwjVvZIAHESlrwkjVizYGXTFchjasT81hMZtJgt6iW8sA7Nu5qx7MVsc2z7UAS0mGhV2a_NEvZaYQ1A0dC19wG2A6bNJIMNEy46oJXlUe8nxb1ezkh4CkO3jUnVIPBo4rney_uwcXj-wc5hiE3a6m7jeHphyy70zDBFD_YRiizZaXzI-LTPGvhuRb7UtfcZuOomQqOuH6xebaoe3OzX9aA7CfWCHIJDhjQJwC-5BR5HQ9k7FCae3L4pWfmUVUOTZEFViJtxazLxOjM_w',
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36'
    },
    body: '{ "headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null}}'
};


it('Should reach testsite', done => {

        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('error:', error);
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
            console.log('body:', body);
            done();
    });
});
```